# Cannot read property 'totalCalls' of undefined

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I am working on AWS Lambda and writing a method in Node.js and when I run the method it gave an error

```
**Cannot read property 'totalCalls' of undefined**
```

here is my code

```js
  const mysql = require('mysql');
  const moment = require("moment");
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME,
  user: process.env.RDS_USERNAME,
  password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.RDS_PORT,
  database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('Events:',event);
  //let QueueID = event['queueId'];
  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if (err) throw err;
     var d = new Date();
        let currentDay = moment(d).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
        console.log('CurrentDay:',currentDay);
        let sub = 6;
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - sub);
        d.setHours(00);
        d.setMinutes(00);
    let sql = `select * from ctrData2.CallDetail WHERE InitiationTimestamp > ? ORDER BY InitiationTimestamp ASC`;
    //let field = [QueueID];
    connection.query(sql,[d], function (err, result, ) {
      if (err) throw err;
    //   connection.release();
       var CallaboveSla =0;
       var weeklySLAObject={};
       result.forEach(d => {
           if(weeklySLAObject[d.RoutingProfileName] !== undefined){
               console.log('Do i comere here',weeklySLAObject)
               weeklySLAObject.RoutingProfileName.totalCalls++;
               if(d.AgentInteractionDuration > 180){
                   if(weeklySLAObject.RoutingProfileName.callsaboveSla){
                       weeklySLAObject.RoutingProfileName.callsaboveSla++;
                   }else{
                       weeklySLAObject.RoutingProfileName.callsaboveSla=0
                   }
               }
           }else{
               weeklySLAObject[d.RoutingProfileName] = {totalCalls: 0,callsaboveSla:0};
           }
            // let date = new Date(d.ConnectedToAgentTimestamp);
            // let DateNow = moment(date).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
            // let datetoday = new Date();
            // datetoday.setDate(datetoday.getDate() - 7); //set it to 6 days back
            // weeklySLAObject.push(d);
            
            });
       let sla = (CallaboveSla/result.length)*100;
       callback(null,weeklySLAObject);
    });
  });
};
```

I have no idea what is this error about

Printed on console and was able to retrieve total.

values are showing in the console but in response, it gave me an error.

Comment: Error tells you that `weeklySLAObject.RoutingProfileName` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking this for undefined:

```
if(weeklySLAObject[d.RoutingProfileName] !== undefined){
```

But then you're accessing another property

```
weeklySLAObject.RoutingProfileName
```

Which should probably be changed to

```
weeklySLAObject[d.RoutingProfileName].totalCalls++
```